# PrimeFaces components are not rendered

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I've developed an application using JSF with PrimeFaces. I've a problem in the Facelets page where `<p:xxx>` tags are not displayed in the page. Here is my Facelets page to display label, textbox and button. Only label is displayed in the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:i="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/touch"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head> 
<body> 
<ui:composition template="/templates/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
    <h:form>  

        <h:outputLabel for="curator" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold"/>  

        <p:inputText id="curator" value="#{user.curator}" />  

        <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display"/>  
</h:form>  
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</body> 
</html>
```

my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Cation</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
      </context-param>
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

     <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please check you have Primefaces jar(s) included in your classpath, also try to change `body` to `h:body`

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi: as to the body, any content outside `<ui:composition>` is **ignored** and therefore irrelevant to the problem. What counts is the master template file `/templates/template.xhtml` which the OP didn't show at all.

Comment: yes you are right BalusC.
@user2476979 please show the template as BalusC mentioned, and also, check server logs, if Primefaces jars are included in classpath, it usually prints something about PF version used

Answer (score 0):

It seems the label is displaying because it is an h-tag whereas the other tags are p, so first off check whether your primefaces jar is implemented by checking the `Libraries` on your project (if using Netbeans ) or `Java Resources\Libraries` if on eclipse. The `xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"` is not sufficient to make primefaces work, it only specifies the namespace.

**Note** : you're tagging `primefaces-extensions` where I think `primefaces` tag is more relevant in your case.